# Haskell what does ++ do

Tags: haskell

What does "++" do? I tried looking it up, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: have you tried looking it up on hoogle?

Comment: using `ghci` you can always check on functions by typing `:t` or `:type`, e.g. `ghci > :t function`, note operators have to be wrapped in parens like this `ghci > :t (++)`. For a bit more information you can use `:i` or `:info`, e.g. `ghci > :info (++)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's list concatenation.

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
[1, 2, 3] ++ [4, 5, 6] == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

See https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1720009.1